# How do you remove a runnable that was posted in a method call that ended?

Tags: android, android-widget, handler, runnable

I have a method that posts a runnable "myRunnable" to a global handler.
The method is called for every widget I put on the screen. So if I put 3 widgets, there's 3 runnables in the message queue. But how can I specifically remove the 2nd runnable from outside of the method, while leaving the other 2 untouched? All 3 runnables are called "myRunnable", and I can't access that variable from outside the method. And removeCallbacks(null) takes everything out, so I can't use that.

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way using two array lists.

**Note: all of my runnables loop infinitely by calling postDelayed(this);**

When I start a runnable for a widget, I add the widget's ID to an array list called *widgetHasRunnable*. Then I have another array list called *stopThisRunnable* which is initially empty. The runnable running on a specific widget checks *stopThisRunnable* to see if it contains this widget's ID, every loop. So now I can add a widget's ID to *stopThisRunnable* from some other part of the program, and that certain runnable's code will go to an else-statement with removeCallbacks(this);